# CSS - background image margin bottom?

Tags: css, html, background, margin

Is it possible?

heres what i got...

```
<div id="mMid">
    <div id="mBot">
      Content
    </div>
</div>

#mBot {
    background:url(/images/mBot.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    width:  1001px; 
}
#mMid {
    background:url(/images/mMid.png) top left repeat-y;
    width:1001px;
}
```

mMid is a vertically tiled image. mBot is a png with a folded corner. 
my problem is that mMid shows through the png of mBot.

can i put like a bottom margin on the mMid bg image? so it stops the 170px from the bottom of the whole div area?

Comment: Could it be an option to not make the png transparent, but instead make it opaque and fill the background with the website background color?

Comment: unfortunately, no, the mBot bg image has to be png. That isn't an option. thats why im having so much difficulty...

Comment: Yes, but png can be opaque as well.

Comment: mis-understood. it is a png. and transparent thats why it was showing the tiled image underneath it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a separate div, and do some tricks using paddings and margins.

In the fiddle, the blue div is the 'Mid' div, and the red div is the content div. They still have the same side and position.
The green div is a trick, and is lowered 170px. 
Now, when you give the green div a background instead of mMid, the background should be lowered 170px relative to the content div.

```css
#mMid {
    width:1001px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    padding-top: 170px;
}

#mTrick {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background:url(/images/mMid.png) top left repeat-y;
}
#mBot {
    background:url(/images/mBot.png) bottom left no-repeat;
    /* width:  1001px;  not needed. It will borrow the size from it's parent */
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: -170px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mMid">
    <div id="mTrick">
      <div id="mBot">
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
        Content<br>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Or view jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/N3z8S/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.bottom { 
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/tags/smiley.gif) no-repeat bottom; 
    clear: both; 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
}
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    some content
    <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, put the background-repeat after the background-position. Change **bottom left** to **120px 130px** (according to what you need). The first value is the horizontal position and the second value is the vertical.

```
background: url(/images/mBot.png) no-repeat 120px 130px;
```

Comment: i dont know if you understood the question.

Comment: your css here is going to move the bg image i dont need moved 120px from the left and 130px from the top.

Comment: It is the repeated image that should be lowered.

Comment: not lowered but raised from the bottom... its ok i did it a different way... my file size is huge now tho because of the lack of the repeating img